# Using ForceIDE, how can I view the system.debug called from a class or trigger? ( I can see the ones from my test Class)

Tags: trigger, debugging, logging

I am using the Eclipse Force.com IDE and have created a test class as well as a trigger. I put a system.debug in both but the Apex Test runner only displays the debug of the test class and not the one from the trigger. I know it goes into the trigger because I filtered through the name and found variables and such.

Is there a way to have the trigger debugs as well? I found this in the community board [post](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/where-can-I-see-quot-System-debug-quot-statement-output/td-p/296427) but it was referencing I imagine the online developer force.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

P.S. I was also wondering if anyone happens to know if the output of the Debug Log (in forceIDE) is saved somewhere. This way I could use a console to view the log and filter it out instead of pasting the log and putting it in a text editor.

Comment: Might as well also specify that I am using a Mac :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to open the debugger in a browser: `Your Name -> Developer Console` in order to view the debug log your referring to when the class is executed.

You can run *anonymous apex* in both the IDE and the online-debugger, and look at the output console for the results.

In the online debugger you can enter a filter (near the button), I usually just put: 'DEBUG' in capitols to get only debug statements when I have the logger turned up to it's highest level.

If you turn down the level you'll get less information, but shorter logs, which means you can review more information about long running classes/methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jordan, When you say I need to open the debugger in a browser do you mean a browser in FORCEIDE? or do I have to go into the developerforce website?

Comment: I mean within the Salesforce.com website, you will see your code executing as you run methods from page controller methods, batch execution, etc.